# When to use SharePointPermissionAttribute

Tags: sharepoint, code-access-security

When do I actually need to decorate my methods with the SharePointPermission attribute? I've come across some code samples that have them and some that don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for decorating your code with SharePointPermission is if you want to deploy your dll to bin (instead of GAC) and you're using a tool like [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) which looks for these CAS (Code Access Security) attributes and build the CAS policy entries in Manifest.xml based on these.